# Why Moq dependency uprev is not working as expected?

Tags: c#, moq, .net-4.6.2

Moq has a dependency hierarchy as follows

```
Moq 4.18.4
  System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions >= 4.5.4
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe >= 4.5.3
```

In my application I must use

```
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe to 4.7.0
```

so from the `Moq` definition, everything is fine..

Whe I'm trying to execute a unit test that uses `AsSpan()` from `System.Memory`,
it throws an exception (during Release and Debug mode).

```
System.IO.FileLoadException
HResult=0x80131040
Message=Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, 
Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its 
dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly 
reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
Source=System.Memory
StackTrace:
   at System.MemoryExtensions.AsSpan(String text)
   at UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod1() in 
   C:\source\repos\ConsoleApp9\UnitTestProject1\UnitTest1.cs:line 13
```

Steps to reproduce:

Create a unit test project with the following nugets:

- Moq Version="4.20.69"
- MSTest.TestAdapter Version="2.2.8"
- MSTest.TestFramework Version="2.2.8"
- System.Memory Version="4.5.4"
- System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe Version="4.7.0"

Try to run (release or debug) and you'll get an exception on the `b = a.AsSpan()` line.

```cs
namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    using System;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            string a = "asdfdsa";
            var b = a.AsSpan();
        }
    }
}
```

Is it a bug? or am I missing something?

Comment: It sounds like your solution is referencing version 4.0.4.1 of `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe` somewhere, seeing as the error message you are getting starts with _Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1_.

Comment: @AstridE.: Moq does refer to 4.0.4.1 - but it does not follow the version uprev of the dependency. I am asking if this is a Moq bug?

Comment: Oh, then I must have misunderstood. Due to the dependency hierarchy that you posted for Moq v4.18.4, I had not expected Moq v4.20.69 to reference an even earlier version of [...].Unsafe than v4.5.3. Unfortunately, I don't know whether it's a Moq bug.